# How to find Named Entity for any Unicode Value

Tags: html, unicode, entity, named-entity-recognition

How to find named entity for any Unicode value, or any ISO characters, for `egrave` the html named entity is `&amp;egrave;`, Unicode is `&amp;#x00C8;`, likewise I am looking for named entity for this symbol ờ (its not `ograve`, its a symbol in Vietnam language) and its Unicode value is `&amp;#x7901;`. Can anyone suggest this and help to find any symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for named entity for this symbol `ờ`

There isn't one. HTML only provides named entities for a small selection of characters, not all of Unicode. The characters available are largely Western and mathematical characters that were commonly in use in the early days of the web back when people's text editors couldn't do Unicode.

These days, other than:

- the characters you have to escape to stop them acting as delimiters (`&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&quot;`), and maybe
- the otherwise-invisible characters (`&nbsp;`, `&shy;`...),

there isn't much good reason to use named entities. Instead just type `ờ` as-is and make sure to save your file with a suitable encoding and declaration (eg UTF-8).

The full list of named entities in HTML5 is [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref); for any other character you must either type it normally or, if you have to work with unfortunate tools that can't support Unicode, use a numeric character reference such as `&#x1EDD;` for U+1EDD Latin Small Letter O With Horn And Grave (`ờ`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But even though I tried &amp;#x1EDD; in that tool but the character is not visible to the browser or output.

Comment: What is “that tool”? What output are you talking about? Why do you need to produce a character reference, can't you just type/paste in `ờ`? Are you actually writing `&amp;#x1EDD;` instead of `&#x1EDD;`?

Comment: Yes is a kind of unicode version of xml viewer, may be its tool bug, thanks for your reply Bobince